# How to create a new column in Pandas Dataframe to indicate if other column's values appeared in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

There is a python array:

`['a', 'b', 'c']`

And a panda data frame:

```
    key value
0   a   1
1   e   2
2   b   3
3   c   4
4   d   5
5   f   6
```

How to add a new column to indicate whether or not values in key is in the array?

Output:

```
    new_col key value
0   True    a   1
1   False   e   2
2   True    b   3
3   True    c   4
4   False   d   5
5   False   f   6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
L =['a', 'b', 'c']
df.insert(0, 'new_col', df['key'].isin(L))
print (df)
   new_col key  value
0     True   a      1
1    False   e      2
2     True   b      3
3     True   c      4
4    False   d      5
5    False   f      6
```

If not necessary first column:

```
L =['a', 'b', 'c']
df['new_col'] = df['key'].isin(L)
print (df)
  key  value  new_col
0   a      1     True
1   e      2    False
2   b      3     True
3   c      4     True
4   d      5    False
5   f      6    False
```